# Eclipse 4 RCP - Part class constructor not called

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I'm new to Eclipse 4 RCP and just learning the basics.
I created a part and gave it a class URI.
For some reason the class's constructor isn't being called.
What could be the reason?

[image: Package Explorer]

[image: Application.e4xmi]

PlaygroundPart code:

```
package com.example.e4.rcp.todo.parts;

public class PlaygroundPart {
    public PlaygroundPart() {
        System.out.print("Example");
    }
}
```

Nothing is printed in the console.

Comment: Do you have '-clearPersistedState' set in the Program Arguments in the Run Configuration for the app?

Comment: I do. http://prntscr.com/6t7nvb
It's in the Launching tab of todo.product

Comment: This is OK for the product but what about the Run Configuration you are using for testing. Is the part actually showing in the UI?

Comment: What do you mean by 'using for testing'?
The part does show: http://prntscr.com/6t7qwb

Comment: You might want to use 'println' rather than 'print' to ensure the message is being flushed to the console. However I can't reproduce this at all, a very similar app works as expected.